# catkin structure

Tags: ros, catkin, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ros community

Im planing on migrating my packages to catkin. However I have a question regarding the structure of the catkin workspace. Currently I have this setup

```
/quadrotor [this is my github repro]
  /controllers
    /controller_1
      -CMakeLists.txt
      -manifest.xml
      /src
    /controller_2
      -CMakeLists.txt
      -manifest.xml
      /src
  /experiments
    /user_1
       /what_evernode_1
         -CMakeLists.txt
         -manifest.xml
         /src
```

So i extensively used folders to structure my ros code. Is there a way i can maintain this hierarchy in catkin? Is it possible to have metapackages of metapackages? then i could easily make for every folder which only holds packages a metapackage.

Thanks a lot for your help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/119581/catkin-structure/) by [ffontana](https://answers.ros.org/users/7296/ffontana/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2014-01-20

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have subfolders in your catkin_ws/src folder which are not valid ros packages without any problem. I think you future catkin workspace structure could be like this:

```
/catkin_ws
 /src
    -CmakeList.txt [symlink by catkin to toplevel cmake]
    /quadrotor [this is my github repro]
      /controllers
        /controller_1
          -CMakeLists.txt
          -package.xml
          /src
        /controller_2
          -CMakeLists.txt
          -package.xml
          /src
      /experiments
        /user_1
           /what_evernode_1
             -CMakeLists.txt
             -package.xml
             /src
  /devel
  /build
```

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should be able to keep this exact code structure with catkin. The only change will be to the workspace layout. The repository with the source code will exist in a dedicated subdirectory to enable out of source builds.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1